# Unity game screen blurred

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There's a problem with my unity game screen. When I switch over to game screen all the sprites are blurred out. The scene view is perfectly fine but the game scene is blurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unity Inspector of Sprite you can set Generate Mip Map is false or you can check format compression.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html