# unity3d ngui button gone/icon,image blurry

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

After compiling/building my apk my button is gone and when I see it in my sprite list all my buttons and icons are blurry, I don't know what the problem is. If I  start over again this will be my 3rd time.

button gone;
[image]

icon is blurry;
[image]

This is what it looks like after I compile the apk successfully.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1 Blurry Image:

[Unity game screen blurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385044/unity-game-screen-blurred/42385193?noredirect=1#comment71956163_42385193)

#### 2 Because it behind your background please check or you can set layer...

Comment: edit: i fixed the problem . changing true color to argb 32 and check readable and change to advanced

Comment: Have a nice day. :D